# how to used {!Community_Url} in Visualforce page email template?

Tags: community, customer-community

i need to reset community user and get URL from valid email id then click link for reset password . i need to used visual-force email template in {!Community_Url}

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `$Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails`?

Comment: thanks @crmprogdev yes i need password reset link from Community_url . this syntax i have got link  but please describe for details .

Comment: Try using Salesforce Help. It's described in detail there how to reset someone's password. It's also described in Getting Started with Communities.